# How to set image position programaticall in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to move image to another x,y coordinates after 3 seconds I try this but I got an error like this: 2012-01-17 14:01:11.417 YapiKrediDemo[2147:207] -[Sozlesme moveImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e07540 My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

image1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GirisButton.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:image1];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3
                                 target: self
                               selector:@selector(moveImage)
                               userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)moveImage:(NSTimer*)timer{

//[image1 setCenter: CGPointMake(634, 126)];
CGRect myFrame = image1.frame;
myFrame.origin.x = 634;
myFrame.origin.y = 126;
image1.frame = myFrame;
}
```

How can I solve this? Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten `:` symbol

```
selector:@selector(moveImage:)
```