# Setting the position of an UIImageView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, position

I'm creating an iOS app that shows several items of a museum. Each item has a certain position on a map of the museum. Their coordinates are stored in an array. So far, so good.
Depending on the item you choose, the position of this item should show up on a map.

I've built the View in Xcode's Interface Builder. I've added an ImageView and set its position to 0 (x+y).

I've added the ImageView as an outlet in my .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myView;
```

Finally in the Views viewDidLoad()-Method I've tried to change the position of the Image View (containing a kind of "pointer-image") after hours of research (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894335/how-to-set-image-position-programaticall-in-objective-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611115/iphone-set-uiimage-position) or even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985334/uiimageview-doesnt-position-properly-on-ipad-always-on-0-0)) like this:

```
[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height)];
```

xCoord and yCoord are float variables containing the coordinates of the item.
I am NSLogging the frame's position before and after the setFrame-method and it tells me that the x and y position of the ImageView has changed. But on my Screen it still appears in the top left corner of the screen.

I've already tried some different methods like this one:

```
CGRect needleOutletFrame = [self.myView frame];
needleOutletFrame.origin.x = xCoord;
needleOutletFrame.origin.y = xCoord;
[self.myView setFrame:needleOutletFrame];
```

Didn't work either ...

Has anyone got a hint for a solution to my problem?

Cheers,
Alex

EDIT:

I've deleted the UIImageView that I had created using Interface Builder and created an UIImageView in ViewWillAppear method by myself:

```
UIImageView *myView;
myView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
myView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ort_nadel_r.png"];
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(257, 90, 300, 300)];
```

I don't know why, but finally it works as I want it to!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that you are setting x and y both to xCoord? From where do you get that the position has changed?

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo ... of course y should be set to yCoord. I also do know already that origin.x is not assignable :-)

I do
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.myView.frame));
before and after changing the position. According to that NSLog-Output the position should have been changed. But it hasn't on the screen.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the position in ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: What would be a more appropriate place than ViewDidLoad? What would you suggest?

Comment: Let's try in viewViewAppear

Comment: Neither viewDidAppear nor viewWillAppear could solve the problem.
Here's the Output of NSLog:
2014-04-23 12:30:54.764 xxx[9353:60b] {{0, 0}, {205, 185}}
2014-04-23 12:30:54.765 xxx[9353:60b] {{257, 90}, {205, 185}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have connected the UIImageView in your view controller then try turning off **auto-layout** to programmatically modify the frame of it:

[image]